# The import org.flywaydb cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, maven, flyway

I am stuck with the error "Error:(4, 0) ajc: The import org.flywaydb cannot be resolved" while compiling my code. I have added the maven dependency as follows

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.flyway}</version>
        </dependency>
```

flyway.version - 4.0.1

It even downloaded all the sources , is that because it is https?
Please help me to resolve this.(i am using flyway with java 1.7,Spring > 4,JPA)

Comment: yes that is right... updated @Thilo

Comment: @user3247425 when you make a clean install, did you see some error/warning? maybe you have some proxy and dont allow you to download the sources

Comment: mvn clean install works fine without any error , even it downloaded the jar file and it is there in .m2 folder . But when i start rebuild form my IDE the jar file is getting removed from my project Libraries .(Using Intellij IDE 15)

Comment: Could you post your whole POM? Maybe this is declared inside `<dependencyManagement>`?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has added support for ajc, which seems to conflict somehow with your build. Try disabling it in Settings > Compiler > Java Compiler.(Might be slightly different in your version.)

Comment: Yes @Tunaki it is inside <dependencyManagement> in my parent pom.xml and i have another maven module where i am actually using FlyWay . there also i have added the dependency  .Posting my whole pom is difficult here.

Comment: @AntonKoscejev disabling is not helping me..